# optimize insert operation in MySQL (InnoDB)

Tags: mysql, mariadb, python

I have this table:

```
create table tab3(
id                              int not null auto_increment,
phrase                          text,
link_1                          int,
link_2                          int,
primary key (id),
foreign key (link_1) references tab1 (id),
foreign key (link_2) references tab2 (id));
```

I am inserting around 400k rows into this table with Python.
this is the insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO tab3(phrase, link_1, link_2)
    VALUES(
        %s,
        (select id from tab1 where tab1.col1 = %s),
        (select id from tab2 where tab2.col2 = %s));
```

I have an index on both tables tab1.col1 and tab2.col2. but the insertion is taking a long time around 5mins/1000 row

I've tried many different techniques [from the official docs of MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-optimization.html#:%7E:text=You%20can%20use%20the%20following,separate%20single%2Drow%20INSERT%20statements.) such as:

- using cursor.execute(stmt,param)
- using cursor.executemany(stmt, param**s**)
- multiple processes ( billiard https://pypi.org/project/billiard/ )
- blocking the commit until all chunk of data is inserted and then commit changes
- encapsulating the insert stmt inside one transaction ( with **START TRANSACTION** )

But None of the above gave a good improvement.

Comment: Save your data for 400k row which must be inserted into your table to the temporary table then insert from this table without correlated subqueries.

Comment: @Akina saving into a Temp table does no take as much time as in a normal table ?

Comment: Your temptable may use `ENGINE=Memory`. Your goal is not to iterate and insert the rowss one-by-one but perform batch insert, insert all rows with one SQL query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using MariaDB there is [this inbuilt improvement in MariaDB-10.7+](https://mariadb.org/10-7-preview-feature-innodb-bulk-insert/) for bulk inserting.

This is for empty tables when `foreign_key_checks=0` and `unique_checks=0`.

In general, regardless of version, consider increasing `innodb-buffer-pool-size` to cover the `tab3` created information and the `tab1`/`tab2` data  being read so most of it is in memory.

Earlier versions may benefit from an increased `innodb-log-file-size`.

Also look at your `phrase`. If this contains short amounts of text a `varchar(max num of characters)` is a better storage type as it avoids some innodb bulk size handling code that does some size/speed tradeoffs.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a temp table; have extra (NULLable) columns for the ids.
2. Insert the data into that table.  Use `LOAD DATA` or batched Inserts (1000 rows) at a time.)
3. Do a single `UPDATE` to batch the setting of the ids for one column.  Ditto for the other column(s).
4. `INSERT...SELECT` top copy all the rows into the 'real' table.
5. `DROP` the table from Step 1.

Here is a discussion of that job.  It also includes inserting new rows, if necessary, into the normalization table(s) (your `tab1` and `tab2`):
[*Normalization*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table#normalization)

This will be a lot faster (about 1 SQL per 1000 rows) than what you have (3 SQLs per row).

(This technique applies whether the target table is empty or not.)

Comment: Hi @Rick James, 
I am trying to implement your suggestion, 
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'Final_df.csv'
INTO TABLE answer_temp
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;
but I'm facing this error 
(MySQLdb.OperationalError) (2068, 'LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE file request rejected due to restrictions on access.')
 ---> even though local_infile is set to ON
---> I also tried this fix https://stackoverflow.com/a/63388772/12944030, but still not working, any suggestion would be very much helpful, thanks

Comment: @moe_ - The "mysql" user (in the OS) needs read permission to the file and read+search permission to the directories above it.  Are you using Windows or some variant of Linux?  For the latter, see `chmod` and related commands.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu, and the mysql user is "root" so it suppose to have permission

Comment: @moe_ - The MySQL server ("mysqld") is running as the _OS_ user "mysql".  See `top` or `ps`.